# How do I pass an ApiKey to my header using axios in a react js App

Tags: reactjs, axios, api-key, request-headers

I was given an Apikey to pass alongside an endpoint as a get Request. I went to Postman and added the endpoint, then in the authorization section I selected Api Key, it showed me the key and values, in the key I placed ApiKey, and in the value, the actual value. When I sent it, it responded well with a status code 200. But in my React App, it returns 401 unauthorized. I suspect I am passing it wrongly or what am I doing wrong? This is my code below

Please I would appreciate any prompt feedback, thanks a lot

I tried to use this, but it showed unauthorized

```
  useState(() => {
        const getAcc = async () => {
            try {
                const res = await axios.get(url, {
                    headers: {
                        "Authorization":{
                            "API Key": `${api_key}`
                        }
                    }
                });
                console.log("resPonseAdd", res)
            } catch (error) {
                console.log("myError",error)
            }
        }

        getAcc()
    }, [])
```

Comment: What header/value (without including the actual key) do you use in your postman request?

Comment: Authorization, then under it Api Key

Under the API KEY, it requested  key and a value. the key I used is ApiKey,a dn it worked. In postman

Answer (score 0):

there is not much context given on the question but I can try to answer with an issue I am seeing in your code.

The `Authorization` header does not accept any random value, it needs some specific format, you can refer to [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Authorization).

All the formats that a value can be passed to `Authorization` header.
Generally most common is `Basic {credentials in base 64}` and `Bearer {token}`
I am guessing in postman it was set to Basic, but you can refer to the actual API documentation where you recieved this API Key.
Hope this solves your problem.

Comment: In postman it was set to API Key

Comment: @OmokefeOvieDavid Is `API Key` a [Postman variable](https://learning.postman.com/docs/sending-requests/variables/) of some sort? Is the value of the variable set to `Bearer YOUR_KEY`?

Comment: an api key was gievn to me by the backend guy and I tried the endpoint in postman, under the authorization part, I selected the apikey aspect, it does mot receive bearer token but the API key. the Api key gave me a key and value pair where I placed my key as APIKey and the pasted the value in the  value section. It worked on postman, but rejected on React

Comment: @BetterReact Developer, Yes, API Jey is a postman variable

Comment: @OmokefeOvieDavid can you give some context in what service API Key you are using, that would help here

Comment: OK, i have resolved it, thnaks

 const res = await axios.get(url, {
                headers: {
                    "ApiKey": `${api_key}`
                }
            })

Answer (score 0):

```
  try {
    const response = await axios.get(url, {
      headers: {
        'Authorization': `Bearer ${apiKey}`,
      },
    });

    console.log('Response:', response.data);
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error:', error);
  }
};

useEffect(()=>{
   getAcc();
},[])
```

Comment: It still says 'API Key not provided